# Context menu "Edit with IDLE" option only half works

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, contextmenu, python-idle

When I right click on a .py file and click the normal "Edit with IDLE" option, it returns an error saying that the file does not have a program associated with it, please install a program or create an association in the default programs control panel (which I've already done). However, if I go to the second option, a sub-menu which also says "Edit with IDLE", then click on "Edit with IDLE 3.5 (32-bit)" then it works fine.

I'm on windows 10, 64 bit, with Python 3.5.2.

My original problem was that edit with IDLE worked but it opened it with Python 2.7, so I uninstalled that, and then later uninstalled Canopy, and all this just made the option in the context window disappear completely. Eventually I uninstalled all python from my computer, made sure the registry was clean, and reinstalled Python 3.5, which is how this current situation started.

I've probably wasted more time trying to fix all this than I'd ever gain in convenience, but it's all sunk cost now.

Comment: On my Win10 machine, the context menu has one `Edit with IDLE    >` entry.  When I hover over it, a submenu opens with `Edit with IDLE 3.5 (`64 bit)` and ditto for 3.6.  I have 2.7 installed but is does not appear.  I am not sure if install options affect this.  Clicking on the entry with submenus, as opposed to one of the submenu entries, has no effect.  In 3.4 and before, there was only `Edit with IDLE` with no submenu.  If you see that, as a separate context menu entry, there must be something left in the registry.  I forget whether there could only be one such entry for the default python.

Comment: Did you actually have a question?  If so, did I answer it?  I will also note that the Windows installer manager changed in 3.5.

Comment: i feel really dumb I didn't actually ask a question. What I meant to ask was how to get the first Edit with IDLE option to work without having to go through the same named sub-menu below it. Although most likely reading your description, what happened was a prior failed attempt to fix it with a registry tweak detailed in another question on this site added the useless extra edit option, and I don't know how to undo it.